# LVM + how to expand sda2 file system while sda is the OS disk

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, lvm

sda2 have only 79.5G and we want to increase it to 150G

lsblk

```
NAME              MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0                 2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda                 8:0    0  600G  0 disk
 +-sda1             8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
 +-sda2             8:2    0 79.5G  0 part
```

what is the procedure to expend sda2 disk to 150G size?

my target is to get atleast 150G under PFree

```
pvs
PV         VG       Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree
/dev/sda2  vg_linux lvm2 a--  79.51g 64.00m
```

filesystem:

```
mount | grep var

/dev/mapper/vg_linux_var on /var type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Comment: What type of filesystem are you using on sda2? Is there free space on sda (for another partition)?

Comment: the filesystem is xfs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several options:

- A: Add another harddrive PV (quick, least risk to existing volumes/partitions)
- B: Add another partition PV (quick)
- C: Resize sda2

I would go with option A:

1. Add additional harddrive >150GB (Linux does not need a reboot for this)
2. Create a PV using the new harddrive

   Assuming your new harddrive is sdb:

   `sudo pvcreate /dev/sdb`
3. Add it to the VG

   `sudo vgextend vg_linux /dev/sdb`
4. Resize LV

   Assuming you want the total size of `/var` to be 230GB:

   `sudo lvresize -L 230G "/dev/mapper/vg_linux_var"`
5. Resize filesystem (no problem with xfs)

   `sudo xfs_growfs /var`

This assuming you will be ok with the free space being available in your VG instead of PV.

Comment: about option A ( from step 2-5)  can you please describe it with commands ?

Comment: can you have another example with option C